# Can I pass a setter (not the value) as parameter to a function without reflection?

Tags: dart

I want to pass the setter of a class' field as parameter to a function so the function can do the assignment.

Is there a way without using reflection?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't directly pass the setter.

To avoid  reflection you can wrap the setter inside a function :

```dart
class A {
  String _attr=;
  set attr(String v) => _attr = v;
}

main() {
  final a = new A();

  // create a wrapper function to set attr
  final setter = (v) => a.attr = v;

  callSetter(setter);
  print(a._attr);
}

callSetter(setterFunction(value)) {
  setterFunction("value");
}
```

This [proposal about generalized tear offs](https://github.com/gbracha/generalizedTearOffs/blob/master/proposal.md#cons) is [approved](http://news.dartlang.org/2015/06/null-aware-operators-and-generalized.html) and will probably implemented soon and allows to closurize getters and setters like:

```
var setter = a#attr;
// and can be invoked like
setter(value)
```

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it like this :

Calling the function:

```
function ( (parameter) => val = parameter );
```

The function body should be like this:

```
void function (setter) {
    setter = newValue;
}
```

Hope it helps, and let me know if does not work.